# WordPress site does not load

Tags: internet

wordpress site doesn't want to open in elementary os, but it opens on windows. The site is hosted on ubuntu 18.04 server and here is the info of the /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
```

## The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

```
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

Comment: This is more WordPress related issue than elementary OS. Please ask in WordPress SE, I can also migrate this for you. And also, I don't think this is because of elementary OS.

Comment: What is your site's address?

Comment: But the site opens in in Windows and other devices. Only doesn't open in elementary os. THe site is hosted on private network.

Comment: So, is this elementary OS machine under the same network? And what browser are you using in elementary OS? Also what are you using to manage cache of WordPress?

Comment: Yes, it is on the same network. I am using crome and firefox.  I have not injected anything to manage WordPress Cache. What do you suggest on that? i would like to try that.

Comment: Please install a caching plugin and clear your sites cache. You can install W3 Total cache or WP Super Cache. I have used both, they are fine and pretty popular in WordPress community. However, you should only one at a time - no need to install both.

Comment: Thank you very much Hasan, will so.